# Getting JSON file out in HTML through Azure Storage

Tags: javascript, html, azure, storage, iot

I have hooked my Particle photon to a eventhub on Azure where i stream the data through Stream Analytics and then to my Azure Storage. Right now i recieve the temperature as a JSON file in Azure Storage.

Is there any way to do HTTP request or something to the storage account?
This is the JSON file: https://pptlbhstorage.blob.core.windows.net/temperature/0_d1e8a2b709b14461b5ac12265f33020b_1.json

Also, should i make a WepAPI that recieves theese data? so i also can make mobile app and not only webpage?

Comment: You want to get the json file from blob storage via javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may get the files out from the Azure Storage using the [official SDKs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/). For that, you will need the Blob functionality - [take a look here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/). 
And, if you want your own implementation, you can use the [Azure Storage REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135733.aspx).

```
 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("ahrimanstoraccount_AzureStorageConnectionString"));
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("vhds");
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("yourfilename.txt");

        string path = (@"C:\Temp\yourlocalfilename.txt");
        blockBlob.DownloadToFile(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```

app.config:

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="ahrimanstoraccount_AzureStorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myAccountName;AccountKey=myAccountKey" />
</appSettings>
```

UPD from the comments: the same approach is working for Console and ASP.NET MVC. Azure Storage may be added by 1) Click on the project => Add => Add Connected Service => Azure Storage => Select your storage account. That will install all of needed libraries and valid connection string into your web.config. 2) Once it is done, the browser will open the page where code pieces will be shown
and manually, by going to the Azure Storage page and copying keys/names to the connection string.

Comment: Thanks! i'm quite new to this.. is it possible to show any code examples? im not so used to read documentation, i have tried but always end up doing it wrong

Comment: @yellowborat you use Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes i do use Visual Studio

Comment: @yellowborat ok, 1) Click on the project => Add => Add Connected Service => Azure Storage => Select your storage account. That will install all of needed libraries and valid connection string into your web.config. 2) Once it is done, the browser will open the page where code pieces will be shown

Comment: As i have some samples, i will post it there a few minutes later.

Comment: @yellowborat here you are. Add Connected Service as described above, go to the web.config, grab the connection string name (in the format i used in the answer) and put your filename. You should be all set.

Comment: Thank you! :D When i try to connect to the Azure Storage i get this message: https://gyazo.com/fa2acb1ca6f0cef5baf9899b0c2d5cd0

Comment: Fantastic. What is the project type? ASP.NET, something else?

Comment: Ok. First, Click on your project, "Manage NuGet packages", go to "Browse" => enter "azure storage", once it find the packages WindowsAzure.Storage and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager, install both of the packages.

Comment: After that, paste the code i provided to your Main class, and open app.config. Paste the appsettings block here as i changed in the answer.

Comment: I have already downloaded the packages needed for azure storage, i went to the connectionstring to manually add my key and storage name. Isn't that the same also?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. See my answer - just paste your key and name to the connection string.

Comment: I got it working now, so what does the code basically do? It opens up the container, and look for the specified blob name? in my case "jsonFile.json" and then saves it locally ?

Comment: Exactly as you said.

Comment: Thank you! Now if i were to display this json file out in html.. how would i do it? would i create a MVC project and then do the same thing as i did here in the controller?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Also you may want to try SignalR for real-time stuff as described [here](http://www.mikelanzetta.com/2015/08/real-time-mapping-with-signalr-and-event-hubs/). It uses Event Hubs, but i suspect you use that or the IoT Hub.

Comment: No i am actually using Event Hubs as the Particle Photon already provides their own cloud service. I will look into SignalR! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @yellowborat Glad that helps. Please mark the question answered for a future reference.

Comment: All -  this isn't the place for conversation - that's what Chat is for. There is a lot of detail buried in the comments here that should actually be in the answer (as well information such as links to errors, which should be edits to the original question).

Comment: Sorry, but when Stackoverflow constraints me with not opening a chat since i don't have enough points, i didn't have any choice :)